# Uniq Command Usage?

Tags: command-line

I have file contents of some stuff and want to use `uniq` command on it but It not works what is the thing i missed?

```
$ cat ornek_2
elma
elma
armut
armut 
erik
kayısı
üzüm
```

With `uniq` command;

```
$ cat ornek_2 | uniq
elma
armut
armut 
erik
kayısı
üzüm
```

With `sort | uniq` command

```
$ cat ornek_2 | sort | uniq
armut
armut 
elma
erik
kayısı
üzüm
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two "armut" lines are not exactly the same. One has a space at the end.

I realized this when I was editing the question. I just so happened to click at the end of the line and noticed the gap between the word and the cursor. But, if I hadn't realized it then, I would have fed the two lines into `uniname` like so, to analyze each character:

```
$ grep "armut" ornek_2 | uniname
character  byte       UTF-32   encoded as     glyph   name
        0          0  000061   61             a      LATIN SMALL LETTER A
        1          1  000072   72             r      LATIN SMALL LETTER R
        2          2  00006D   6D             m      LATIN SMALL LETTER M
        3          3  000075   75             u      LATIN SMALL LETTER U
        4          4  000074   74             t      LATIN SMALL LETTER T
        5          5  00000A   0A                     LINE FEED (LF)
        6          6  000061   61             a      LATIN SMALL LETTER A
        7          7  000072   72             r      LATIN SMALL LETTER R
        8          8  00006D   6D             m      LATIN SMALL LETTER M
        9          9  000075   75             u      LATIN SMALL LETTER U
       10         10  000074   74             t      LATIN SMALL LETTER T
       11         11  000020   20                     SPACE
       12         12  00000A   0A                     LINE FEED (LF)
```

See character 11 in the above output

If you want to check if any other lines end with whitespace (spaces, tabs, etc), you can use grep:

```
$ grep -E '\s+$' ornek_2
armut 
üzüm
```

---

BTW, you don't need pipe `cat` into `uniq` or `sort`. You can just run `uniq ornek_2` or `sort ornek_2 | uniq`, though it's not a big deal in this case. More details here: [Should I care about unnecessary cats? - Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16279/117037)

Comment: how do you know one has a space at the end?

Comment: your edit not changed the answer

Comment: the edit was tangential

Comment: I've edited the answer again to explain.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your sample file . I got your error too . But when I wrote *armut* again by myself problem solved !!!

If you copy this text from anywhere type them down in your file again .

```
sort a | uniq -ic
  2 armut
  2 elma
  1 erik
  1 kayısı
  1 üzüm
```

Comment: i tried your offer but the no changed

Comment: @solfish i tried to write down again and it works as you see !  Don't copy . Copy may bring some extra charechter . Use `od filename` to see original file on disk .

Comment: ok second one has problem